# How to pray for a corrupt government involved in drug trafficking?

Tags: prayer, civil-government, drugs, intercession

Venezuelan government/regime is destroying the country through corruption, drugtraffiking to the USA and Europe, murder, kleptocracy, unjustified imprisonments. The government palace is full of symbols and objects of demon worship and "santero" altars.

They are starving the population of the country without water, electricity, gasoline, security, health care, justice, etc. Venezuela seems to be the pre-apocalyptic laboratory!

Should I consider them as the authorities imposed by God, in order to pray for them and not against them?
How should I pray?

Comment: Do you want a Catholic answer or one from another Christian denomination?

Comment: You can always pray that a government will be just and will protect the innocent.

Comment: @curiousdannii there is a standard prayer during the prayers of the faithful part of the Mass that our deacon intones.  I'll get the words from him tomorrow, I think that's actually a decent answer to the question.

Comment: I would appreciate a Bible based answer. Independent of any denomination. Just citing the word of God.

Answer (score 6):

The Bible tells Christians to pray for those in positions of authority.  Such authorities include government officials (international, national, and local) and pastors, church elders, school boards, school principals, employers, and the like.  There is an underlying principle behind this:

> Let everyone be subject to the governing authorities, for there is no authority except that which God has established. The authorities that exist have been established by God (Romans 13:1).

This applies even when the authorities are cruel, unjust and persecute God’s people.  Even when the Israelites were in exile, God told them to pray for their Babylonian captors:

> Seek the peace and prosperity of the city to which I have carried you into exile. Pray to the LORD for it, because if it prospers, you too will prosper (Jeremiah 29:7).

Here is an important Bible verse about such prayers:

> I urge, then, first of all, that petitions, prayers, intercession and thanksgiving be made for all people—for kings and all those in authority, that we may live peaceful and quiet lives in all godliness and holiness. This is good, and pleases God our Saviour, who wants all people to be saved and to come to a knowledge of the truth (1 Timothy 2:1-4).

When those in authority are obeying the will of God, it is easier to “live peaceful and quiet lives in all godliness and holiness” (1 Timothy 2:2). But when evil men are in authority, our prayers for them are just as needed, as illustrated by William Tyndale’s last words as he was being burned at the stake:

> “Lord, open the King of England’s eyes.”

When Christians pray for God’s will to be done on earth as it is done in heaven, that prayer should include Governments, rulers and those in authority.  God will deal with those who go against His will and they will answer to Him for their deeds.  Our part is to lead peaceful and godly lives so that we are pleasing to God.

Comment: Thank you very much Lesley. I´m living in Venezuela. We have two presidents: One is in  full power and authority,  but illegitimate, since he got in to office through poll manipulation. He is involved with drugtraffiking, and all perversities you can imagine. He has a headprice of 20.000.000 USD, if captured by DEA. Is he the authority I should pray for? The other has been elected by the legitimate (and not government recognized), people elected congress, but has no power. Which is the God imposed authority? It is difficult to decide.

Comment: You and your people are in an impossible situation.  Christians are commanded to obey the authorities appointed over them - but not if those laws go contrary to God's laws.  We are then to obey God, rather than men. We are to fear Him who can destroy both body and soul (Luke 12:4-5) and to acknowledge Jesus before men (Luke 12:8-12). We must leave the rest up to God.

Answer (score 1):

Denominations with a liturgical tradition often have prayers specifically for the government, and there is no assumption that such a government will be godly. For example here are two prayers from the Anglican Church of Canada:

> for Elizabeth our Queen and all the Royal Family,
>   for N the Prime Minister
>   and for the government of this country,
>   for N the premier of this province
>   and the members of the legislature,
>   for N the mayor of this municipality
>   and those who serve with him/her
>   on the (city, town, village, district) council, †
>   for all who serve the common good,
>   **that by God’s help
>   they may seek justice and truth,
>   and live in peace and concord.**

(N means to insert the name here)

> Defend our liberties and give those whom we
>   have entrusted with the authority of government the spirit of
>   wisdom, that there may be justice and peace in our land.

The Church of England has very similar prayers.